# First difference data frame

Tags: r

I have the folowing data frame:

```
>dados

COUNTRY   Year   CO2 emissions Pop. Growth(%)
Argentina  1994      1.23         0.3
Argentina  1995      1.26         0.2
Argentina  1996      1.28         0.4
Argentina  1997      1.24         0.2
Brazil     1994      1.54         0.7
Brazil     1995      1.59         0.6
Brazil     1996      1.60         0.9
Brazil     1997      1.58         1.3
```

And I'd like to first difference the variables `CO2 emissions` and `Pop. Growth(%)` for each country. I've already tried the function `dados[,2:4] <- diff(dados[,2:4])` but it's returned the error:

> "Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] :  non-numeric
>   argument to binary operator"

Comment: Can you please share what output you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(COUNTRY) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(CO2_emissions:Pop_Growth), funs(.-lag(.)))
```

**Edit: As of `dplyr 0.8.0`, `funs()` is soft deprecated. Use the following instead for newer versions of `dplyr`**

```
df %>%
  group_by(COUNTRY) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(CO2_emissions:Pop_Growth), list(~ .x - lag(.x)))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   COUNTRY [2]
  COUNTRY    Year CO2_emissions Pop_Growth
  <fct>     <int>         <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Argentina  1994         NA        NA    
2 Argentina  1995          0.03     -0.100
3 Argentina  1996          0.02      0.2  
4 Argentina  1997         -0.04     -0.2  
5 Brazil     1994         NA        NA    
6 Brazil     1995          0.05     -0.100
7 Brazil     1996          0.01      0.3  
8 Brazil     1997         -0.02      0.4
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(COUNTRY = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Argentina", "Brazil"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 
    1997L), CO2_emissions = c(1.23, 1.26, 1.28, 1.24, 1.54, 1.59, 
    1.6, 1.58), Pop_Growth = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6, 
    0.9, 1.3)), .Names = c("COUNTRY", "Year", "CO2_emissions", 
"Pop_Growth"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Very useful! Thank you.

Comment: For newer versions of `dplyr` it's recommend to use `list()` the above will return `funs() is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0
please use list() instead`

Comment: @Sav-econ Thanks for the comment. I've added an example for the new syntax.